# How to edit Moodle's config.php when moving from localhost to hosting

Tags: localhost, hosting, moodle

When I try enter my moodle from internet I see this message:

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

I don't know how I can fix it. What did I do?

1. I entered my filizilla.
2. My domain folder is empty so I put my moodle_data folder and moodle-2.3.11 folder (I tried to put moodle_data folder in the root where I see all my folders)
3. I created a data base in my hosting.
4. I updated my config.php but I'm not sure what I have to put in this lines:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'localhost/moodle-2.3.11';// I should put subgominio.com/moodle-2.3.11/

$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:\\xampp\\moodledata';// I don't have idea what I have to put here, because I put in the root.

$CFG->admin     = 'admin'; // I don't have any idea which information put here
```

5. When I opened this link `bookstore.mainstreetschoolhouseinc.com` I see my files and after I open the folder moodle-2.3.11 and I see this message:

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Answer (score 6):

For the wwwroot you should include http and remove the trailing slash

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://subgominio.com/moodle-2.3.11';
```

For security, the data root needs to be outside of the www root.

For example, if your site is in

```
/home/subgominio/public_html/moodle-2.3.11
```

Then the data root should be in

```
/home/subgominio/moodle_data
```

You will also need to change the permissions of the folder to 02777 so it is writeable.

Then change the config to

```
$CFG->dataroot = '/home/subgominio/moodle_data';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. You have to do this in the config file

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://example.com/';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/path.../moodledata';
```

and change the permissions of the folder `moodledata` to `777` so it is writeable.